# TypeError: decoding str is not supported (converting bytes into str)

Tags: python, byte, decoding

I have this code

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        c, a = self.sock.accept()
        print(c)
        name = c.recv(1024)
        people = ""
        self.name_list.append(str(name, 'utf-8'))
        num_g = len(self.name_list)
        c.send(bytes(str(num_g), 'utf-8'))
        print((str(num_g)))

        data = str(c.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
        print(data)
        if str(data) == "ok":
            for name in self.name_list:
                print(name)
                c.send(bytes(name, 'utf-8'))
        print(len(self.name_list))
        print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())+" "+str(name, 'utf-8')+ " is connected")
```

and i get this error

```
    File "./server.py", line 51, in run
    print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())+" "+str(name, 'utf-8')+ " is connected")
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

i don't understand why i get this error. when i receive the bytes from connection,

```
name = c.recv(1024)
```

the name is in bytes, that's why i tried to make it string when i print that line

Comment: try `print("{0} {1} is connected".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()), name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already converted that name to a `str`.

The line

```
self.name_list.append(str(name, 'utf-8'))
```

converts the name to a string and saves it a list.

Then

```
for name in self.name_list:
```

loops over those names, and at the end of the `for` loop the value of `name` is the final converted name in `self.name_list`.

So when you do

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())+" "+str(name, 'utf-8')+ " is connected")
```

It's using *that* name, not the raw one returned by `name = c.recv(1024)`

The simple solution is to use a different variable name in that `for` loop which processes `self.name_list`.